Do the Vedas mention the origin of evil and death?
In Puranas and Adi Parva from Mahabharata, the evil is found from Adharma's birth from the back of Brahma. At same time, This chapter of Shanti Parva from Mahabhatata mentiones that the evil is originated by demons of lust and wrath.

Having achieved great progress in righteousness, men in those days worshipped only all good qualities that they saw. The Asuras, however, O child, could not bear that righteousness which prevailed in the world. Multiplying (in both number and energy), the Asuras (in the form of Lust and Wrath) entered the bodies of men. Then was pride generated in men that is so destructive of righteousness.

Meanwhile, the death is existed though Mrityu, the son of Adharma/the lady created by Brahma (from Drona and Shanti Parvas).
However, Does the Vedas mention the origin of evil and death?
